# Bootstrap 3 image displaying

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, geometry, css-position

Hi I have question regarding css and javascript, here is link with image http://personal.crocodoc.com/YvRh8Hd

What I want to do is position smaller circles around big one. I am using bootstrap 3 and want to keep responsiveness on circles. What would be the best way to do positioning? The simple way I am going is defining in css positions

```
.one {
    left: 260px;
    top: -30px;
}

.two {
    top: 50px;
    left: 310px;
}

.three {
    right: -100px;
    top: 140px;
}
```

the problem is when I resize browser to smaller(to fit tablet screen or phone), circles hover each other, they should be positioned vertically inline. Thank You for Your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact science, but you can use css media queries to adjust for various screen sizes to re-work your positioning.

Something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .one {
    left: @left;
    top: -@top;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 599px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  .one {
    left: @left/2;
    top: -@top/2;
  }
}
```

If you're recompiling bootstrap's LESS, then they have screen sizes pre-defined: 
@screen-xs, @screen-sm, @screen-md, @screen-lg

I've used variables to suggest you half the left/top dimensions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries